# Only charge capacitor when button pushed then turn on LED momentarily with capacitor when button released

Tags: capacitor, pcb, circuit-design

I am trying to make circuit to turn on an LED momentarily. I would like to charge the capacitor when the button is pushed, then when released turn on the LED momentarily with the capacitor.

[image: my circuit]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only have a push-to-make switch:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPWOJa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Just consider that in this case the cap will not be charged up to the full 5V so you might need to adapt the resistor R1.

Comment: Use a Schottky diode and the capacitor voltage will only be about 0.3V lower, maybe drop current by 20% (barely noticeable to the eye) with a blue or white LED.

Answer (score 5):

Try using a change-over type of push-button, also called a single pole dual throw (SPDT) switch. Connect it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxQnlU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You could put the resistor in the path of the capacitor to avoid high current when charging the capacitor and possibly damaging it.

Answer (score 3):

You could build a circuit like this with SPDT switch

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVQ4ZT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>