# Only charge capacitor when button pushed then turn on 12 VDC motor momentarily with capacitor when button released

Tags: capacitor, pcb, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, circuit-design

Can I turn on a DC motor momentarily with this circuit if I replace LED with 12 VDC motor?

I need help making a circuit to turn on 12 VDC motor momentarily with push button. So if I push button, the 12 VDC motor not activate, but when I release it the DC motor will be active momentarily; what should I do?

[image: Existing schematic]

Comment: What current does the motor require, and how long do you want it to run after releasing the button?  It is not likely to run at all with the 5 volt power supply you show.

Comment: idont know, i use the parfume sprayer dc motor & about 1+ minute 1. what should i change? can i just only change the input?

Comment: Please put that information in your question.  The more information you provide, the more likely someone will be able to help you.  You won't be able to run much of a motor for a minute with the charge stored in a capacitor.

Comment: Related (previous, w/ LED): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/451765/2028

Answer (score 2):

You can use an optocoupler if the motor is small, otherwise, you can use the output of the optocoupler to turn on the motor driver. Here is the circuit of the optocoupler, notice the LED that turns on the transistor on the other side.

[image]

Here is the circuit with the optocoupler substituting the LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flZbYl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>